# Performance of function in Clojure 1.3

Tags: performance, clojure

I was wondering if someone could help me with the performance of this code snippet in Clojure 1.3. I am trying to implement a simple function that takes two vectors and does a sum of products.

So let's say the vectors are X (size 10,000 elements) and B (size 3 elements), and the sum of products are stored in a vector Y, mathematically it looks like this:

Y0 = B0*X2 + B1*X1 + B2*X0

Y1 = B0*X3 + B1*X2 + B2*X1

Y2 = B0*X4 + B1*X3 + B2*X2

and so on ...

For this example, the size of Y will end up being 9997, which corresponds to (10,000 - 3). I've set up the function to accept any size of X and B.

Here's the code: It basically takes `(count b)` elements at a time from X, reverses it, maps `*` onto B and sums the contents of the resulting sequence to produce an element of Y.

```
(defn filt [b-vec x-vec]
  (loop [n 0 sig x-vec result []]
    (if (= n (- (count x-vec) (count b-vec)))
      result
      (recur (inc n) (rest sig) (conj result (->> sig
                                                  (take (count b-vec))
                                                  (reverse)
                                                  (map * b-vec)
                                                  (apply +)))))))
```

Upon letting X be `(vec (range 1 10001))` and B being `[1 2 3]`, this function takes approximately 6 seconds to run. I was hoping someone could suggest improvements to the run time, whether it be algorithmic, or perhaps a language detail I might be abusing.

Thanks!

P.S. I have done `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)` but don't get any reflection warning messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using count many times unnecessary. Below code calculate count one time only

```
(defn filt [b-vec x-vec]
  (let [bc (count b-vec) xc (count x-vec)]
    (loop [n 0 sig x-vec result []]
        (if (= n (- xc bc))
          result
          (recur (inc n) (rest sig) (conj result (->> sig
                                                  (take bc)
                                                  (reverse)
                                                  (map * b-vec)
                                                  (apply +)))))))) 


(time (def b (filt [1 2 3] (range 10000))))
=> "Elapsed time: 50.892536 msecs"
```

Comment: Might it also be possible to avoid the recurring calls to reverse by reversing the B vector once instead of parts of the X vector hundreds of times?  I don't know Clojure, but this seems like a lot of extra work.

Comment: Actually the reverse call is on the elements taken from x-vec (i.e the sig is being reversed)

Comment: If the x-vec has size 10000, then we'll have to make 3333 calls to reverse to reverse those sets of 3 elements that we're taking from it, won't we?  But if we just reverse the b-vec once, we should be able to avoid them.  Or it might be the middle of the night, and I might need sleep.

Comment: Yup, that can be an optimization, that would make `Y0 = B0*X2 + B1*X1 + B2*X0` operation to `Y0 = B2*X0 + B1*X1 +  B0*X2` .. which is fine

Comment: OK, I'll post it as a secondary answer, too.  You've already got my +1.  I found a wonderful Try Clojure online page...maybe I should take a look at this language.  This was kinda fun.

Comment: Thanks Ankur. This is a tremendous improvement! Coming from a C++ background, I always thought of size of a vector as being a very fast operation (i.e. just a subtraction of two iterator positions). I guess (count coll) counts the collection everytime.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want top performance for this kind of calculation, you should use arrays rather than vectors. Arrays have a number of performance advantages:

- They support O(1) indexed lookup and writes - marginally better than vectors which are O(log32 n)
- They are mutable, so you don't need to construct new arrays all the time - you can just create a single array to serve as the output buffer
- They are represented as Java arrays under the hood, so benefit from the various array optimisations built into the JVM
- You can use primitive arrays (e.g. of Java doubles) which are much faster than if you use boxed number objects

Code would be something like:

```
(defn filt [^doubles b-arr 
            ^doubles x-arr]
     (let [bc (count b-arr) 
           xc (count x-arr)
           rc (inc (- xc bc))
           result ^doubles (double-array rc)]
       (dotimes [i rc]
         (dotimes [j bc]
           (aset result i (+ (aget result i) (* (aget x-arr (+ i j)) (aget b-arr j))))))
       result))
```

Comment: So I tried this version and got it to run. I converted b-vec and x-vec into Java arrays like this: `(def b-arr (into-array Double b-vec))` and `(def x-arr (into-array Double x-vec))`. However, this version of the code ran much slower than the optimized versions provided by Ankur and Ian. On average, I got roughly 25 msec with the purely functional version, but around 850 msec with the Java array version. Any suggestions?

Comment: You will want to use primitive arrays for `b-arr` and `x-arr`. Try `(def b-arr (double-array b-vec))`

Comment: OK, I figured out why this native Java version was slow. I replaced `defn filt[b-arr x-arr]` with `defn filt[^doubles b-arr ^doubles x-arr]` and it got to run very fast. Thanks for your answer, wish I could mark your answer as accepted too. This whole exercise has been very helpful to me.

Comment: Ah, looks like I was adding a comment just while you were, and didn't notice until I had posted. Anyway, I tried what you suggested too, but had to type-hint the function's arguments to observe the massive speedup. I suppose the downside of using native Java arrays is that one loses the concurrency niceties of immutable persistent data structures.

Answer (score 3):

To follow on to Ankur's excellent answer, you can also avoid repeated calls to the reverse function, which gets us even a little more performance.

```
(defn filt [b-vec x-vec]
  (let [bc (count b-vec) xc (count x-vec) bb-vec (reverse b-vec)]
    (loop [n 0 sig x-vec result []]
        (if (= n (- xc bc))
          result
          (recur (inc n) (rest sig) (conj result (->> sig
                                                  (take bc)
                                                  (map * bb-vec)
                                                  (apply +))))))))
```